# Is the series $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5!}-...$ divergent, absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is the series $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5!}-...$
divergent, absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent?

Firstly, this is an alternating series, if I could somehow find its general term, maybe I could see some light. I notice that we could have two parts $\sum \limits _{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n +1)!}- \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n}$. I don't see a way forward.

Comment: Finding a general term is much more than you need to determine whether a sequence converges or not. Do you know any tests you could apply here? For instance, how do you check for absolute convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two parts you observe are absolutely convergent and divergent, respectively. Thus we should expect the series to diverge